# Remove message within a loop or lapply statement after then message is displayed

Tags: r

My question is fairly basic, although I have done a fair bit of searching and cannot find a solution.

I am running `lapply` and custom functions on large datasets and like to embed a `message` statement so I have an idea of how far through the process I am at any given point in time. I  have noticed that in some functions that R will provide a message with progress then remove that message to only include a given snapshot in time (i.e. R showing progress in % - say 13 % - then removing the progress to only illustrate progress at a given moment in time - such as 15 % without having to see 13 % ever existed).

How to I message then remove the message in a `lapply` function or `loop`? Below is an example on a small dataset where I display a message that I would like removed when the next message is printed.

```
iris_numcols <- iris %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% colnames()

lapply(iris_numcols, function(x){
  
  message(paste0('Calculating mean value of', x))
  
  mean(iris[[x]])
  
  })
```

Output

```
Calculating mean value ofSepal.Length
Calculating mean value ofSepal.Width
Calculating mean value ofPetal.Length
Calculating mean value ofPetal.Width
```

Comment: First off, `print`, despite its name, *is not intended for printing text!* (at least non-interactively). As you can see from the output it creates, it's instead intended for R's auto-printing functionality on the interactive terminal. To print text, use `message`, `cat` or `writeLines` instead (check their respective documentation for details).

Comment: Thanks Konrad! I am using `message` at the moment so I can replace my `print` statements with `message`. I had a look in the documentation and couldn't see how I could achieve what I was wanting to achieve with `message` (i.e. display and removing messages in a loop). I updated my question with `message` rather than `print`. Any tips on how I can achieve this with `message`?

Comment: not really an answer to your question but maybe useful: the package `pbapply` contains apply functions with a progressbar.  `pbapply::pblapply(...)`  solves the trouble of not seing the progress while lapply is running.

Comment: @chipsin Can you give us an example of a function with such behavior? Looking at its source code might help understand what's going on.

Comment: @Robert Hacken, when data is read using `data.table::fread` there is a progress bar. As `fread` progresses in loading in data the progress bar is replaced with a new progress bar illustrating the progress at that given moment in time. I'll have a look at some scripts I have to find other examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how `txtProgressBar()` achieves this, you can use `cat()` in combination with `"\r"` special character (carriage return) to return to the beginning of the current line in the console and overwrite it. However, you can't change anything above the current line this way.

```r
iris_numcols <- iris %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% colnames()

lapply(iris_numcols, function(x) {
  
  cat(paste('\rCalculating mean value of', x))
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
  mean(iris[[x]])
})
```

This might become problematic in some instances, though. Quoting from `?txtProgressBar()`:

> Using style 2 or 3 or reducing the value with style = 1 uses \r to return to the left margin – the interpretation of carriage return is up to the terminal or console in which R is running, and this is liable to produce ugly output on a connection other than a terminal, including when stdout() is redirected to a file.